# Uploading my IconSet in xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode6

Good morning,

I'm trying to upload my icons images for my first App and I'm having real problems knowing he sizes for each one of the devices and the "x2 and x3". I have checked a lot of websites, even the official one, to have an explanation of the sizes for each one but there is nothing about that.

I'm going to post an image and I would like to know if you can tell me what sizes I have to put in every place because I'm always getting warnings.

Here you are:
http://wiraj.com/1.jpg

**What size I have to put in each space?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have icon 29 x 29,

For 1x the icon size should be 29 x 29

For 2x the icon size should be 58 x 58, means double the size of 1x icons

For 3x the icon size should be 87 x 87, means triple the size of 1x icons